# copy all file nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

How to copy all the files from 'bucketname/one/two/one.file' to another bucket can anyone edit my code to perform such thing

```
  var params = {
  Bucket: "destinationbucket", 
  CopySource: "/sourcebucket/HappyFacejpg", 
  Key: "HappyFaceCopyjpg"
 };
 s3.copyObject(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

For a single file copy, you can use this method. For the whole folder, you need to list the files from the source folder, then copy the files. The sample working code is,

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./AwsConfig.json');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    params: {
        Bucket: bucketName
    },
    region: XXX
});

// list all files from source folder
s3.listObjects({
    Prefix: sourceFolder
}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } // an error occurred
    else {
        if (data.Contents.length) {
            for (i = 1; i <= data.Contents.length; i++) {
                if (data.Contents[i]) {
                    var params = {
                        CopySource: bucketName + '/' + data.Contents[i].Key,
                        Key: data.Contents[i].Key.replace(sourceFolder, destinationFolder)
                    };
                    // copy object to destination folder
                    s3.copyObject(params, function (copyErr, copyData) {
                        if (copyErr) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Copied: ', params.Key);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Try this @Dusky Dood
**Updated Code**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./AwsConfig.json');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

// region: 'ap-southeast-2'

// list all files from source folder
s3.listObjects({
    Bucket: "sourceBucket",
    Prefix: "sourceFolder"
}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } // an error occurred
    else {
        if (data.Contents.length) {
            for (i = 1; i <= data.Contents.length; i++) {
                if (data.Contents[i]) {
                    var params = {
                        Bucket: "destinationBucket",
                        Key: data.Contents[i].Key
                    };
                    // copy object to destination folder
                    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                        console.log('uploaded') // File uploads correctly.
                    });
                    // s3.copyObject(params, function (copyErr, copyData) {
                    //     if (copyErr) {
                    //         console.log(err);
                    //     } else {
                    //         console.log('Copied: ', params.Key);
                    //     }
                    // });
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Update2**
Here is the exact code what I exact used,

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./AwsConfig.json');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

// region: 'ap-southeast-2'

// list all files from source folder
s3.listObjects({
    Bucket: "bucket1", // source bucket name
    Prefix: "report" // source folder
}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } // an error occurred
    else {
        if (data.Contents.length) {
            for (i = 1; i <= data.Contents.length; i++) {
                if (data.Contents[i]) {
                    var params = {
                        Bucket: "bucket2", // second bucket ie) destination
                        // new folder: reportNew inside second bucket 
                        Key: `reportNew/${data.Contents[i].Key}`.replace('report/', '')
                    };
                    // copy object to destination folder
                    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                        console.log('uploaded') // File uploads correctly.
                    });
                    // s3.copyObject(params, function (copyErr, copyData) {
                    //     if (copyErr) {
                    //         console.log(err);
                    //     } else {
                    //         console.log('Copied: ', params.Key);
                    //     }
                    // });
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to copy files from a folder in bucketA to some folder in BucketB is that possible in above code

Comment: first one is copy the folders inside the same bucket. Updated one is copy the folders into other buckets. @DuskyDood

Comment: but I want to copy files in a folder of a bucket to another folder in another bucket can you get me

Comment: Is this an actual coding requirement you have, or are you doing some form of test/certification?

Comment: It's a requirement

Comment: The code is updated with correct code. Replace the folder names with urs @DuskyDood

Comment: @Prabha what does this .replace do Key: `reportNew/${data.Contents[i].Key}`.replace('report/', '')

Comment: You can save on level of indentation by returning early `if (!data.Contents.length) { return; }`